# Convergence of a sequence satisfying a recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am dealing with the following problem:

"Study the convergence of the sequence defined by $52x_{n+1}=x_n^3+96$ with $x_1=5$"

MY ATTEMPT: I have first thought of taking limits in the recurrence relation and I obtained that, if convergent, the sequence has limit $L=2$,$L=6$ or $L=-8$. Then, I have computed that $x_2=4.25$, so I have tried to prove that it is a decreasing sequence with limit 2 (not possible -8 because it takes positive values). Decreasing:
$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x_n^3+96}{52}-x_n=\frac{x_n^3-52x_n+96}{52}=\frac{(x_n-2)(x_n-6)(x_n+8)}{52}$. To determine this is $\leq 0$ (and so it is decreasing), I have seen that $x_n>2$ and $x_n<6$ by the method of induction (don't know for sure if it can be used in this case though). So it is decreasing and bounded, therefore $x_n$ is convergent to 2.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Prove first that $x_n\leq 6$ and $x_n\geq 2$ by induction. You will get it right away, since $(6^3+96)/52=6$ and $(2^3+96)/52=2$.

Comment: Ok, so then it is a decreasing sequence with limit 2, isn't it?